# JQuery : form POST issue

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I'm trying to use the data of a form to create a JSON file that I can use in other pages of my app.

I'm using JQuery Mobile and its [POST method.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
But I don't manage to have any kind of results and I don't know why.
This is my code.

```
<form id="#formK">
    <label>Text
        <input type="text" name="header" />
    </label>
    <div data-role="button" id="save" />Save</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#save").click( function(){
    $.post("OptJson.php", {head : $('[name=header]').val(); }, json );
});

</script>
```

And this is the source of my OptJson.php page

```
<?php
echo $_POST['head'] ;    
?>
```

Where are the errors ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon from `head : $('[name=header]').val();`

If I run your code in my Chrome browser I get the following message: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`. The semi-colon is a *statement terminator* and you don't want to terminate that statement, you just want to call the function and use the result as an argument.

The argument you are sending is a JavaScript object, and you construct it like this:

```
var myObject = {
   data: "stuff",
   otherData: getStuff()
};
```

**Not** like this:

```
//THIS IS WRONG
var myObject = {
   data: "stuff";
   otherData: getStuff();
};
//THIS IS WRONG
```

Notice the different use of semi-colons.

**Edit:** Also, the `dataType` parameter has to be specified as a string, so `"json"`, not `json`.

I would strongly recommend you use the web developer tools that exist in most modern browsers (I prefer Chrome's, but Firefox has good ones too). Check the "Console" tab and see what errors the browser reports. It will help tons when debugging your JavaScript code.

**Edit2:** If you want to actually see the data returned you have to use the success callback like so:

```
$.post("OptJson.php", {head : $('[name=header]').val() }, function(data){
    alert(data); //do stuff with returned data
}, "json");
```

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the semicolon , but again there are no results.

Comment: Oh, you need to write `"json"`, not `json` as the type.

Comment: Okay, then I think it's something on your server side. Using the developer tools in your web browser, please check if the request is being sent and if it is, what is returned from the web server (usually something is always returned, even if its just an error). In Chrome, check the Network tab. In Firefox (with Firebug) check the Net tab.

Comment: I checked the Network Tab. The status of the POST is OK.
In the "preview" tab I can see the source of my page with the correct text displayed, but if I load my page it's empty.

Comment: Hmm.. You realise that `$.post` is an asynchronous function, right? It won't return a page for your browser to load, it will return data that you will have to work with. Check out the success callback here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Hmm... I've just started coding, I'm a noob.  So, what I have to do to write the data of the form on a JSON file ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "write the data of the form on a JSON file". Do you want to save the JSON to a file on disk, on the server?

Comment: Yes. Or better, this was my idea. I need to use these data in a lot of different pages in my app, and I thought this was the way . But probably, I'm wrong :)

Comment: Well, designing your server application is way outside the scope of this question, but if you need to save a file to disc, check out this PHP function for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to upvote and/or mark an answer as accepted if you are content with it. ;-)